# Dotnetbrowser running in outlook vsto loosing keypress

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, dotnetbrowser

We have an Add-in to outlook (VSTO) that contains a form with a webbrowser([Dotnetbrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser)).

On startup everything works as expected but as soon as the form looses focus, one clicks on a mail for example, the DNB doesn't receive any keyboard inputs.
It does however receive mouse input.

We've tried several different versions of DNB.

This has nothing to do with js, as no js is running on the loaded url. The form the browser is in receives keyboard input and should pass it on fine. If it runs in a regular windows form it behaves fine.

Comment: Have you tried tocntacting web browser developers? Do another browsers work correctly (Awesomium, IE web browser control)?

Comment: Yes, we've tried most of the ones out there, and this one is the closest to work out of the box. We're currently running this in evaluation and thus have limited support from their side. This problem occurs only in their Heavyweight(hardware accelerated version), but their lightweight has other/ worse problems so using that isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known keyboard focus issue in DotNetBrowser. This issue has been reported by a few customers, and we are currently working on a proper solution for this issue.

This issue may be reproducible in your case too and cause the behavior that you have described.

Could you please contact DotNetBrowser evaluation support via e-mail and provide a complete sample that can be used to reproduce the issue? In this case we can check that it is the same issue, and start another investigation if this is not the case.